# Reset Survey every month - SharePoint OnLine

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey

I created a Survey application to evaluate my users' opinions.
The problem is that I want to evaluate them every month, except I always have to recreate a new Survey.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Surveys don't have an option to recur. Maybe, and with a doubtful maybe, you could create a survey in SP, export it and schedule to import it as a new survey monthly. An alternative option could be to clear the previous survey - which more likely could be done via a workflow - and then have the users to fill the same survey.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft Flow doesn't allow you to do that!  Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of resetting a Survey.

It is like every other SharePoint list, and once you fill that list up with data there isn't a  way to clear all the data beside manually going in and deleting each item  thus losing the history of the survey.

You could try to export the list to excel, empty the workbook and save it back to SharePoint.

Or you can also create a survey with questions(without answers). Save this survey as a template. Then Use PowerShell to create the survey based on the custom template. This can be run as a timer job and create a empty survey(with questions) list every month.